# The selenium got the different html source from my local pc

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I fetched `http://book.flypeach.com/default.aspx?ao=B2CZHTW&ori=TPE&des=KIX&dep=2015-06-12-undefined-undefined&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&langculture=zh-TW&bLFF=false` by **driver.current_url**

However I got timeout **error** by  this code

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { @driver.find_element(:css => "div.WrapperFlightDate") }
```

But I can see the css attributes `div.WrapperFlightDate` was truly exsiting in the page_source,

How could it happen ?

Answer (score 1):

When I opened given link and trying to see given class in source code(ctrl + u),I didn't find given class.May be page was not loaded properly.

I refreshed page and right click on page -> View Page Source option then got this class in source code.Even I also ran this successfully in FF.

I also surprised why I didn't see correct source code first time.
You also try same,hope so you also get correct code now :).